# Intellij Idea: Disable kotlin file expansion in project explorer

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

How can i disable expanding of kotlin and kotlin script file in intellij idea. its start happening in the version 2018.3 and i cannot find the option to disable it.

[image: intellij]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the menu lies in the top-right corner of `Project` view, untick `Show members`.

[image]